# Wound healing/ scratch assay using ImageJ2 and the Slide Set Plugin, need scratch width and area

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

I am using the Slide set download from https://b.nanes.org/slideset/example1.html to try to measure the cell migration within a wound healing assay. We use 96 well plates, measuring 4 times a day, so an automated method would be best. With this slide set, I am able to use the broder statistics multichannel option from the slide set plugin to measure the area. I am unable to find anyway to measure the scratch width quickly with these methods, any suggestions?

Ive tried all of the parameters in the region option with no success in identifying the width

Comment: I've removed unrelated "mit-scratch" tag (it has nothing to do with scratches :) )